# What desktop environment should I choose for gaming?

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, games, desktop-environments

I'm finally getting rid of Windows for good. Now I'm looking for a good desktop environment for gaming performance.

Which desktop environments are best for gaming? Do some environments have features that make them more suitable for gaming?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Question like this that are open ended should be posted in the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org), please see the [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for what is on-topic here, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest KDE. It has the ability to suspend compositing on full screen applications. That increases the performance a lot.

Besides KDE you should choose a DE that doesn't use any compositing (desktop effects) such as XFCE or LXDE.
See this benchmark test:
http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_1210beta_desktops&num=2

keep in mind that Unity in Ubuntu is getting a lot of attention performance-wise. Ubuntu 12.10 isn't too bad for gaming. That's my personal opinion.